# Should I use IE9's "IE8 document mode" to debug IE8 support?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom

I'm developing a webapp with fairly complex DOM interactions.

- Is IE9's "IE8 document mode" a reasonably good emulation of IE8 rendering?

Failing that, is Is there a way to have both IE8 and 9 on the same Windows 7 computer? I'll definitely test on 'normal' IE8 before release, but if I can work out most of the issues on my own dev machine, that'd be nice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is reasonably good, and it is pretty easy to use, so I would. But it is nevertheless a good idea to do a final check on IE8. You can install a program like IETester, that allows you to use multiple versions of IE, but it is not very stable and has some quirks too. The best thing would be to use a virtual machine for the different platforms and browsers you want to test on. You'll only need to do the testing on the VM after everything works in IE8 mode.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows 7, use the XP Mode to run IE 8. This allows you to run IE 9 in Windows 7 and IE 8 inside a XP virtual machine.